# When serving files with nginx , the browser shows the html file content in all javascript files

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

I have build a project on node, express,angular js and have deployed using nginx but when I see the source code in the browser , I find that all the javascript files are loaded with HTML content. What could be the possible reason.?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9GnG.png)

Comment: I think your question is not clear.

Comment: You probably have an Express app that defaults to sending back the HTML code, combined with an incorrect setup to serve the static resources like JS/CSS files. You should post your Express code.

Comment: I am serving files using express.static and the path is also correct..In local it is running but in deployment i am using nginx to serve. could you help me understand why is this happening.?